# get more than one intent match in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow get a list from dialogflow, through an API call, that can test the user input against all intents (like detectIntent) and get more then just the #1 match.

I'm trying to write middleware that can serve as an extra layer of confirmation where every confidence level between < 0.3 and > 0.7 will trigger the bot say "I'm not sure what you meant, did you mean one of the following?" and then in the quick options it would list a training phrase from the top 3 matches.

Is this possible somehow through the API or the dialogflow console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible with Dialogflow. 
Dialogflow will return just the matched intent and it's confidence score.

You may want to check out [LUIS](https://www.luis.ai/) or [RASA](https://rasa.com/) for this functionality, they return the confidence score of all the intents.

You can deploy agent with same intents on LUIS/RASA.
You can first hit dialogflow, if it return Fallback intent, then hit LUIS/RASA for suggesting **did you mean one of these**.